# I am not able to insert text area values

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html

I have this text box, text area and PHP code for sending it in table. When I am trying to submit the form it's juts getting blank and even else part is also not working.

Code-

```
<form action="" method="post" class="niceform">

 <fieldset>                        

   <dl><dd>&nbsp;</dd></dl>
    <dl>
    <dt>
      <label for="service">Service Name:</label>
    </dt>
      <dd><input type="text" name="service_name" id="" size="39" /></dd>
    </dl>

    <dl>
       <dt><label for="comments">Comments:</label></dt>
       <dd>
        <textarea name="comments" id="comments" rows="5" cols="36"></textarea>
       </dd>
    </dl>

    <dl class="submit">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
      <br />
      <br />
     </dl>

     <?php

        $service_name = $_POST['service_name'];
        $comment = $_POST['comments'];
        mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
        mysql_select_db("easylaw");

        $query = "INSERT INTO service_cat VALUES('','$service_name','$comment')";
        mysql_query($query);
        $result = mysql_affected_rows();
        if($result==1)
        {
     ?>
           <div class="valid_box">Your Record Submitted. </div>
     <?php
        }
         else
        {
        ?>
           <div class="warning_box">Something is Wrong.</div>
        }
       <?php
       ?>               

       </fieldset>

      </form>
```

Can any body tell me what can be the problem so that it's not going and nothing is showing too..

Thanks :)

Comment: what's in the contents of $_POST when you submit the form? var_dump($_POST);

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: Your script is vulnerable to database tampering via SQL Injection. Please filter your `$_POST` inputs as in `$service_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['service_name']);`

Comment: Do check if there are characters like `'` or `"` in your comments box. If so, you'll have to use a `mysql_real_escape_string()` function. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: It's working now...I have filtered $_POST with your given script..

Real Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="warning_box">Something is Wrong.</div>
```

should be

```
<div class="warning_box">Something is Wrong.</div><?php
```

and the following

```
<?php
```

has to be removed.

Comment: Yes it's working now..

Sorry for this mistake..will check from next time.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of column-type does the comment field have in your database? This should be varchar or (long|medium)text.

Change this: `mysql_query($sql);` to `mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());` to produce some kind of error message which makes debugging much easier!

Also your script is vulnerable for sql-injection; escape the user input with the mysql_real_escape_string() function. Or use a database abstraction layer like PDO.

Although you are not obliged to state the column names, I would advise to do it anyway. This is the whole syntax of the mysql insert-statement.

```
INSERT [LOW_PRIORITY | DELAYED | HIGH_PRIORITY] [IGNORE]
[INTO] tbl_name [(col_name,...)]
{VALUES | VALUE} ({expr | DEFAULT},...),(...),...
[ ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  col_name=expr
    [, col_name=expr] ... ]
```

Comment: I have used it as "LongText". Means column type is longtext.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for if -else

```
if($result==1)
{
   echo"<div class='valid_box'>Your Record Submitted. </div>";
}
else
{
   echo"<div class='warning_box'>Something is Wrong.</div>";
}
```